# MongoDB: Replicate chunk across multiple shards

Tags: mongodb, replication, sharding

I have deployed a MongoDB sharded cluster consisting of three replica sets (`config`, `dbms1`, `dbms2`), with a single node in each, based on [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/).

The field `mydb.article.category` has exactly two possible values `"science"` and `"technology"`. I have to create two chunks based on this field such that

- `chunk1` is stored on `dbms1` and `dbms2`
- `chunk2` is stored on `dbms2`

I have been able to distribute the two chunks across shards like this:

```
> sh.status()
  ...
  shards:
        {  "_id" : "dbms1",  "host" : "dbms1/172.18.0.23:27017",  "state" : 1 }
        {  "_id" : "dbms2",  "host" : "dbms2/172.18.0.24:27017",  "state" : 1 }
  ...

> sh.enableSharding("mydb")
> sh.shardCollection("mydb.article", { category : 1 })
> sh.disableBalancing("mydb.article")

> sh.splitAt("mydb.article", { category: "science" })
> sh.splitAt("mydb.article", { category: "technology" })
> sh.moveChunk("mydb.article", { category: "science" }, "dbms1")
> sh.moveChunk("mydb.article", { category: "technology" }, "dbms2")

> sh.status()
...
db.article
  ...
  { "category" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "category" : "science" } on : dbms1 Timestamp(2, 1)
  { "category" : "science" } -->> { "category" : "technology" } on : dbms1 Timestamp(1, 3)
  { "category" : "technology" } -->> { "category" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : dbms2 Timestamp(2, 0)
```

However, I cannot figure out how to replicate `chunk1` on `dbms2`.

I have the impression that this is not possible on the mongo level, as mongo's sharding seems to be *above* replication, i.e. it is not possible to replicate across replica sets. What alternatives are there to achieve this setup?

(This is for a school project about distributed databases.)

Comment: This might be spoilers for a school project, but you need to reconsider your shard key granularity. If `chunk1` cannot be further subdivided you cannot have it exist on more than one shard. It is definitely possibly to configure shard affinity for a range of shard key values. A low cardinality shard key (for example, with two values) is not a typical (or generally useful) approach for sharding since this severely limits the distribution of data and the efficiency of queries. I assume that isn't relevant for your project, but this isn't an approach you'd want to use in a real world deployment.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Stennie. I think my description was not clear enough; what I need is: 1) shard into `chunk1` and `chunk2`, 2) replicate `chunk1` on both *clusters*. I.e. I don't want to subdivide, but want redundant storage for that chunk.

Comment: A chunk is a logical range of contiguous shard key values that always maps to a single shard. Data redundancy in a sharded cluster is provided by replication: each shard is backed by a replica set (required in MongoDB 3.6+, optional in earlier versions). If you want multiple copies of `chunk1`, shard `dbms1` should be a replica set with the appropriate number of data bearing nodes (for example, a 3 member replica set).